$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 4abc$ has no positive integer solutions
Prove that the equation $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 4abc$ has no solutions in positive integers.
Some attempts could be found at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2213995p16779355
but none of them seem to work. I also tried to see if there is a factorization in a reasonable ring extension such as $\mathbb{Z}[2^{1/3}]$, but found nothing useful. (Update: It is also probably the case that it is only important that $a,b,c$ are all non-zero.)
Any help appreciated!

I might try using the factorization $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2−ab−bc−ca)$

Sure, thought about that; also $a$, $b$, $c$ could be treated with $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$, but still $(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) = abc$ does not lead to good coprimality arguments and good distribution of factors in the left-hand side, if I am not mistaken.

Hum this seems tight $264, 448, 511$ has a difference of only $1$, so there are probably other large triplets that almost work... Also $3abc$ and $5abc$ seems to have plenty of solutions.

note that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 4 abc,$  itself,   is irreducible over the rationals or the reals or the complexes. There are tests for that.

Without loss of generality, at least one of $a, b, c$ must be relatively prime to $3$, else you can factor $27$ from both sides of the equation to get a smaller solution, which can't go on forever.  Similarly, not all of $a, b, c$ are even, so exactly two of them must be even.  Considering the equation in $\Bbb Z/3 \Bbb Z$ shows that it's possible to relabel the numbers so that $(a, b, c) \equiv (0, 1, 2) \pmod 3$.  That's all I've got.

Purely local methods will fail because, if $x=1, y=0, z = -1$  then $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 4xyz =0$   The condition that all three be positive is crucial.

@WillJagy Is it crucial that all three be positive or that all three be non-zero?  If the latter, then I can see some hope for what you call "purely local methods."

@RobertShore  you have a point.

If there are any solutions, there must be a primitive solution where $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime. If any two of $a,b,c$ share a common factor, then the third must also contain that  factor. $(da)^3+(db)^3+(dc)^3=4(da)(db)(dc)$ can be reduced by abstracting the factor of $d^3$ that appears in each term. So best to solve assuming coprimality, as non-coprime solutions are trivial extensions of primitve solutions.

If a primitive solution exists, since the RHS is even, only one of $a,b,c$ is even. WLOG, assume $2^n\mid a$. Then $2^{n+2}\mid 4abc$. Since $3n\ge n+2$, it is the case that $(b^3+c^3)\equiv 0 \bmod 2^{n+2}$. Keeping in mind $b$ and $c$ are odd, $b^3+c^3=(b+c)(b^2-bc+c^2)$ implies that $(b+c) \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{n+2}$

well, why not. You mention factoring. As you say, $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz$  factors over the rationals and factors completely over the complexes,  by adding in cube roots of $1.$  However, your variant $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 4xyz$ does not factor over any field of characteristic zero.   The proof is just that this matrix is of full rank, that being $8.$  A discussion in English in
Polynomials with Special Regard to Reducibility  by A. Schinzel,   especially Corollary 3  on page 213.  He credits W. Ruppert, 1986, Reduzibilitat ebener Kurven, J. Reine Angew. Math. volume 369, pages 167-191
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -4 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Just curious why you chose the array environment over the pmatrix environment.  The spacing between columns looks a little off to me.

@RobertShore  I have changed the "r"  column parameter to "c"  which centers. Not sure that addresses you comment, as the distances between consecutive columns do seem to vary. Meanwhile, it is my program that   spits out the Latex code  for the matrix, also a version acceptable for Pari/gp, which then finds the rank.  It would not take that much time to have it also  give the matrix  using pmatrix, but I'll need to fiddle with it.

$a^3+b^3+c^3=4abc$ defines a nonsingular irreducible curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ over $\mathbb Q$. Since the defining equation is cubic, it has genus $1$. It has the rational point $(1:-1:0)$, so it is an elliptic curve. Now we ask Magma to do the following for us:
P2<a, b, c> := ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(), 2);
C := Curve(P2, a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 4*a*b*c);
pt := C![1, -1, 0];
E1, phi1 := EllipticCurve(C, pt);
E2, m1, m2 := MinimalModel(E1);
E2;
MordellWeilGroup(E2);

and it tells us that a minimal Weierstrass model of this curve is given by $y^2+y=x^3+x^2-23x-50$ (LMFDB label 37.b2), and that it has Mordell--Weil group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Since cyclically permuting the coordinates of $(1:-1:0)$ gives three distinct points on the original curve, these are the only rational solutions. Thus multiples of cyclically permuted $(1,-1,0)$ are the only integer solutions to $a^3+b^3+c^3=4abc$.

This answer is correct, and is how I would go about solving this problem. However, you essentially outsource the entire problem (doing a descent on $E_2$) to Magma (and/or the LMFDB). It could therefore be greatly improved by actually doing the descent by hand. One could either do a full $2$-descent (see Silverman Chapter 10) or better, by a $3$-isogeny descent.

The conductor $37$ is very special, and in fact the calculation on this very curve even appears in the literature! See Mazur and Swinnerton-Dyer's paper "Arithmetic of Weil curves" Proposition 1 (your $E_2$ is their $F'$).

Actually while I'm here, I should mention the challenge problem: show that there are no rational points on the curve $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 15xyz$ with $x,y,z \geq 0$. This is fun because the above approach doesn't work.

@Mummytheturkey $2$-descent would require working in a cubic field, and I never learned how to do $3$-descent by hand... for the $x^3+y^3+z^3=15xyz$ question it is enough to show that there are no rational points on the bounded real component of the relevant elliptic curve, and this can be done using the analytic identification of $E(\mathbb C)$ and ${\bb C}/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is its period lattice.

You can also use PARI/GP code ellidentify(ellinit(ellfromeqn(x^3+y^3+1^3-4*x*y*1)))[1] /* ["37b1", [0, 1, 1, -23, -50], []] */.

COMMENT.- My doctoral thesis at Montpellier University (France) was about elliptic curves, I am aware that numerical calculations with such curves are practically inaccessible without computers and in this sense I value any achievement in the reduction or simplification of said calculations.
Here I transfer the proposed problem to a second degree curve (I practically solve the problem but I want to put it as a comment and not as an answer).
For positive integer $c$ fixed in $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 4abc$ we can look at the equation
$$x^3+y^3+c^3=4cxy\hspace 2cm (*)$$ wich defines  a non singular cubic with an oval enclosed in the blue square of opposite vertices $P=(\dfrac c2,\dfrac c2)$ and $Q=(2c,2c)$ so the only points of the curve with both coordinates positive are in this oval and for all of these points $(x,y)$ we have $\dfrac c2\lt x,y\lt2c$ (this remark could leads maybe to solve the problem).

By the particular form of the equation $(*)$, the oval of the curve turns out to be an ellipse. In fact, for all positive integer $c$, we can verify that the equation of this ellipse is given by
$$\frac{(x+y-2.45161c)^2}{1.58173382c^2}+\frac{(-x+y)^2}{0.46732673c^2}=1\hspace 2cm (**)$$ where certainly the coefficients in $(**)$ are approximated and very complicated in their exact forms. This equation corresponds to
$$\frac{(x+y-2\gamma)^2}{2(\gamma-\alpha)^2}+\frac{(-x+y)^2}{(\gamma-\delta)^2+(\gamma-\epsilon)^2}=1\hspace 2cm (***)$$
where  $A=(\alpha,\alpha),\space B=(\beta,\beta),\space C=(\gamma,\gamma)$ and $D=(\delta,\epsilon)$ where these values are solutions of two elementary systems of two equations of straight lines and the cubic from which we get the center $C$ and the  major $\overline{AC}$ and minor $\overline{CD}$ axis. The values $\gamma, \alpha$ are irrational of the third degree over $\mathbb Q$ and $\delta,\epsilon$ are of second degree over $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.
Now if $(a,b,c)$ is an integer positive solution in $(*)$ then taking $X=a+b$ and $Y=a-b$ we have the equation  $$\frac{(X-\lambda)^2}{\mu}+\frac{Y^2}{\nu}=1$$ ellipse where $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ are algebraic irrational of distinct fields. We have
$$Y=\sqrt{\frac{\mu\nu-(X-\lambda)^2\nu}{\mu}}$$
Can $Y$ be a positive rational integer? Certainly not. (End of the COMMENT).

I may have an approach, but not the finished solution, for this... Without loss of generality, we may order the positive integers
$$a \ge b \ge c$$
Now there exist integers $d, e \ge 0$ such that
$$ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 4abc$$
$$ a^3 + (a-d)^3 + (a-e)^3 = 4a(a-d)(a-e)$$
$$ a^3 - (d+e)a^2 - (3d^2-4de+3e^2)a + (d^3+e^3) = 0$$
This is a cubic equation which has a general solution
$$
Q = \sqrt{(2b^3-9abc+27a^2d)^2-4(b^2-3ac)^3}
$$
$$
C = \sqrt[3]{\frac12(Q+2b^3-9abc+27a^2d)}
$$
$$
x_1 = -\frac{b}{3a}-\frac{C}{3a}-\frac{b^2-3ac}{3aC}
$$
$$
x_2 = -\frac{b}{3a}+\frac{C(1+i\sqrt3)}{6a}+\frac{(1-i\sqrt3)(b^2-3ac)}{6aC}
$$
$$
x_3 = -\frac{b}{3a}+\frac{C(1-i\sqrt3)}{6a}+\frac{(1+i\sqrt3)(b^2-3ac)}{6aC}
$$
(original at https://i.sstatic.net/19bmmyO3.jpg)
of the form $Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$ where
$$\textbf{A} = 1$$
$$\textbf{B} = -d-e$$
$$\textbf{C} = -3d^2+4de-3e^2$$
$$\textbf{D} = d^3+e^3$$
Heuristically, it is seen to be extremely unlikely for all of $x, d, e$ to simultaneously be diophantine.
A finished proof should require careful sifting of all the branching cases under the constraint of all diophantine variables.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Since you haven't inserted MathJax in response to @Shaun's comment, I've done it. Please check that it is correct, and also please do it yourself in the future, however. I suspect the down-votes may be due to including (fairly straightforward) equations by image rather than by text. Thanks!

@BrianTung thank you very much, (apologies for not updating the MathJax, I am not a regular user and this is not my usual field of interest)
